# AS3 - e:MouseEvent = null?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I was reading a tutorial on how you can make a turret follow the mouse, for a game, and I stumbled across something I've never seen before.

```
private function showGhostTurret(e:MouseEvent = null):void 
{
    var target_placeholder:Sprite = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
    ghost_turret.x = target_placeholder.x; 
    ghost_turret.y = target_placeholder.y;
    ghost_turret.visible = true;
}
```

I've never seen someone set the (e:Event) to null, like in the first line. Could someone please explain the purpose of doing this? Let me know if you need more information to answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [default parameter value](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html). What it means is that the parameter `e` is optional so you can opt to not include it in a call to `showGhostTurret()` and `e` will be assigned the value `null`.

I'm not sure how that's useful in this particular case since, looking at the body of the function, `e` is most definitely required. You said this was part of a tutorial -- maybe it becomes useful later on?

Comment: It's useful when you want to call the method somewhere else in your code, as well as when the event fires. Although, that only works if you don't actually need to use the `event` property (b/c it can be null). In this example, using this strategy would create a run time excpeption :)